# fetching data from multiple table using join

Tags: mysql

It seems the query is not an easy one to understand. So am trying to make it easy. Following are my create table queries and insert into queries...

```
create table test(
  eancode varchar(50)
  );

create table tab_fr(
  eancode varchar(50),
  product varchar(50)
  );


create table tab_it(
  eancode varchar(50),
  product varchar(50)
  );

create table tab_at(
  eancode varchar(50),
  product varchar(50)
  );
insert into test (eancode) values ('1');

insert into test (eancode) values ('2');
insert into test (eancode) values ('3');
insert into test (eancode) values ('4');


insert into tab_fr (eancode,product) values ('1','prod1');

insert into tab_fr (eancode,product) values ('2','prod2');

insert into tab_fr (eancode,product) values ('3','prod3');

insert into tab_fr (eancode,product) values ('4','prod4');

insert into tab_it (eancode,product) values ('1','prod1');
insert into tab_it (eancode,product) values ('3','prod3');


insert into tab_at (eancode,product) values ('2','prod2');
insert into tab_at (eancode,product) values ('4','prod4');
```

Now I want to retrieve the data in the following format:

test.eancode|    tab_fr.product|    tab_it.product| tab_at.product|

---

1           |       prod1    |    prod1        |    NULL

2           |       prod2     |   NULL         |    prod2

3           |       prod3     |   prod3        |    NULL

4           |      prod4      |   NULL         |    prod4

I hope this new format and sample data can be easily understood. Looking forward for your help.

Comment: Can you improve the formatting? And please use proper joins

Comment: @Strawberry I have reformatted but not sure whether it will be handy for you or not! am new to this forum. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing my original answer so it is easier for you to read:

What you need is to use an OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT test.eancode, tab_fr.product, tab_it.product, tab_at.product 
FROM   test 
LEFT JOIN tab_fr ON test.eancode = tab_fr.eancode 
LEFT JOIN tab_it ON test.eancode = tab_it.eancode 
LEFT JOIN tab_at ON test.eancode = tab_at.eancode;
```

Do some investigation into OUTER JOINS, which take missing values into consideration.

Jon

Comment: John I have 4 tables test, tab_f,tab_i,tab_a...now these 3 tables (tab_fr,tab_i,tab a) has a column ean, price. Now in test there is a  column ean. Now I want to display the price of each eans  from all this 3 tables. If there is any ean which price is not present in any table that will be displaying blank.

Comment: I understand this, but you still haven't provided any data.  Please provide the data that is in your tables so that I can reproduce your error.

Comment: Here you go. What you need is to use an OUTER JOIN

SELECT  test.eancode, tab_fr.product, 
        tab_it.product, tab_at.product 
FROM    test 
LEFT JOIN tab_fr ON test.eancode = tab_fr.eancode   
LEFT JOIN tab_it ON test.eancode = tab_it.eancode  
LEFT JOIN tab_at ON test.eancode = tab_at.eancode;

Do some investigation into OUTER JOINS, which take missing values into consideration.